# Nhibernate exception: base {NHibernate.HibernateException} = {"illegal access to loading collection"}

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am working on an NHibernate exception :"base {NHibernate.HibernateException} = {"illegal access to loading collection"}"

Table PatRef is Parent table.
Table PatCon is Sub table.
When I retrieve data from PatRef to PatCons at debuging mode, the error message screen shot is below.

[image]

The Nhibernate data mapping screenshots are below.

Parent Table PatRef:

[image]

[image]

Sub Table PatCon:
[image]

[image]

The implement for PatRefManagerProp.GetById
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue caused by:"a boolean field in your Project class may be marked as a varchar field in the database".

I have a database column "ON_DIALYSIS" "VARCHAR2(1)", it was mapping as a bool in mapping class PatCon

public virtual bool OnDialysis
        {
            get { return _onDialysis; }
            set { _onDialysis = value; }
        }

After fix the mapping(change bool to string), everything became beautiful :-)

public virtual string OnDialysis
        {
            get { return _onDialysis; }
            set { _onDialysis = value; }
        }

Answer (score 1):

Anytime I've seen this it has been caused by an attempt to access a lazily loaded collection when the `ISession` used to retrieve the object has been disposed or no longer exists.

You can fix this by attaching the entity to another session using `ISession.Lock(entity, LockMode.None)`.

Just a note of warning - you can't attach a transient entity to a session.

(Great detail in the original question by the way. +1 for that)